# Is Java 7 available for M1 Mac?

Tags: java, java-7, apple-m1

Is there a Java 7 binary release for Apple Silicon available anywhere? I have an old app to maintain and getting that to run on Java 8 would be a really risky exercise.

Comment: I think the actual risk is running on a old unsupported JVM that has no security patches for several years now.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but migrating a non-trivial app from Java 7 directly to Java 11 was, for me, one of the least painful migrations I've ever done.

Comment: This app is Grails 2.0.3 and makes extensive use of GORM. Would need to get it to Grails 2.5.6 for Java 8. All kinds of stuff will break and there aren't a lot of tests :(

Comment: Java Almanac [says “no”](https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/7/). Well,  at least not running natively (arm64, aarch64). You may be able to run the x64 edition of Java 7 on Apple Silicon via [*Rosetta 2*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2). But I too strongly recommend you try migrating your app and its dependencies to Java 17, Java 11, or Java 8. Migration may go easier than you fear.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The “seeking recommendations” reason for closure is meant to avoid silly endless debates such as “Which IDE is best?”. That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The M1 official support starts at Java 17 AFAIR (surely newer version than Java 11), however you can use [*Rosetta 2*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2) to run it on your machine

Answer (score -1):

I have Mac m2 chip

I use iReport, try to dowload and install jdk1.7 for x86_64 for Mac, believe me it's work.

To see all the installed JDK use the command in the terminal

/usr/libexec/java_home -V

I've used version .zip not .dmg for iRepor

Of course, you need to set in /etc/ireport.conf your jdkhome.